# String subscript out of range (C++)

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having trouble with this blasted exam question that i cannot put down, visual C++ 2010 keeps telling me: "Expression: string subscript out of range". I figured that I am running the loop longer than the length of the "inStringP.length()" so I have added & subtracted 1 or 2 from the integer in the for loop's conditional test but this leads to no success. Google isn't feeling its usual genius self today either.....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "stdAfx.h"
using namespace std;

string removeChar(string inStringP){
   string temp;
   for(int i=0;i<inStringP.length()-1;i++){
      if(inStringP[i]!='p'){
         temp[i]=inStringP[i];
      }
   }
   return temp;
}

int main(){
   string sample = "Peter picks a peck of pickled peppers";
   cout<<removeChar(sample)<<endl;

   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application crashes is because below statement doesn't allocate any elements for `temp`, accessing `temp[0]` is **undefined behavior**.

```
string temp;
```

If you want to use `temp` inside removeChar function, the better way is to pass const reference to inStringP

```
string removeChar(const string& inStringP){
}
```

By doing that, you don't need to make a copy to inStringP when enter removeChar function.

The better way is to follow [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

Try:

```
string removeChar(string inStringP)
{
    return inStringP.erase(std::remove(sample.begin(), sample.end(), 'p'), sample.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) `temp` before using

```
string temp;

temp.resize(inStringP.size());
```

When you don't know the real size in the beginning, you can [`append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) and [`operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+=):

```
temp.append(1, inStringP[i]);

or

temp.push_back(inStringP[i]);

or

temp += inStringP[i];
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted? string temp needs to be given some size if you're accessing it via element or the compiler wont know how big to make it.  When you say temp[i]=inStringP[i], temp[i] may be out of bounds?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers but i gotta go with the "temp.resize....", worked first time, thanks again & damn QUICK response!

Answer (score 0):

could you try using string.erase()?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

The iterator version will let you delete a character... search through the string using the iterator and then delete it using the erase function, which accepts the iterator as an argument

EDIT: See billz's answer... very nice!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend;

```
string removeChar(string inStringP){
   string temp;
   int len = inStringP.length();
   for(int i = 0;i < len;i++){
      if(inStringP[i] != 'p'){
        temp.push_back(inStringP[i]);
      }
   }
   return temp;
}
```

Because your logic gives no-compile time error but it is a run time error. Your code actually works as:

```
string temp;
    temp[0] = 'P';
    temp[1] = 'e';
    temp[2] = 't';
    temp[3] = 'e';
    temp[4] = 'r';
    temp[5] = ' ';
    //s[6] = 'p';
    temp[7] = 'i';
```

which is an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `std::string` you can make use of arithmetic operators too.

You can do something like this,

```
   for(int i=0;i<=inStringP.length();i++)
   {
      if(inStringP[i]!='p')
      {
         temp += inStringP[i];
         cout<<temp<<endl;
      }
   }
```

I tried your code on `g++ 4.6.3` it did not give any error. However, it gave 
a blank `temp` at the end of `for` loop;

With, `temp[i] = inString[i]` the compiler doesn't yet have a size for `temp`

Also, if you use same `i` for `temp` and `inStringP` 
Suppose, we are at character `e` it will skip the `if block` and +1 `i`. The corresponding
location in `temp` will remain whatever it is.

Also, `string.length()` returns length of string excluding `\0`